# Does OpenNebula automatically provision multiple FS Datastores?

Tags: opennebula

I have an OpenNebula server with the following FS Datastore configuration:

Files: 200GB (Host Storage)
Storage1: 11TB (iSCSI SAN Mounted Drive)
Storage2: 11TB (iSCSI SAN Mounted Drive)

Currently, OpenNebula is defaulting to "Files" datastore. When creating a Template's storage, there is no option to target the disk's datastore.

I'm seeking clarification if OpenNebula will automatically provision VirtualMachine storage to "Storage1 and Storage2" once "Files" is filled?

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a new Image you can specify the images Datastore using the --datastore option in the oneimage create][1](http://docs.opennebula.org/4.14/user/references/cli.html) command

If you are creating a new VM Template you can add a [SCHED_DS_REQUIREMENTS](http://docs.opennebula.org/4.14/user/references/template.html#placement-section) attribute that will be used by the scheduler to choose the best system Datastore for this VM.

If you are deploying the VM manually you can provide the system Datastore as an argument of the onevm deploy command